# Texto anidado + condicional en un menú de un botón html + javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, css, html5

Tengo un botón que se despliega un menú, pero en el menú necesito tener una condicional.

Al pulsar en el botón se despliega el menú como se muestra en la siguiente imagen con el error que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un error en la siguiente linea de código:

```
"<li> "+
    "<a @{ if (Model.ListBtn.Where(x => x.Contains('Exportar')).Count() == 0) { <text> visibility:hidden </text> } }"+" "+" id='btnExcel'><i class='fa fa-download'></i>&nbsp; Exportar a Excel</a> "+
 "</li> "+
```

El el menú solo me debe mostrar el icono mas el texto "Exportar a Excel" y ahora se muestra parte del código, como se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor su apoyo para determinar la sintaxis y que no me muestre parte del código en el menú.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, no es clara.

Answer (score 1):

Debido a la poca información suministrada la respuesta podría ser la siguiente

```
"prevString" + (Model.ListBtn.Where(x => x.Contains('Exportar')).Count() != 0 ? 
"<li>"+
    "<a id='btnExcel'><i class='fa fa-download'></i>&nbsp; Exportar a Excel</a>"+
 "</li>" : null) + "nextString"
```

también podrías utilizar [string interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
$"prevString {(Model.ListBtn.Where(x => x.Contains('Exportar')).Count() != 0 ? 
"<li>"+
    "<a id='btnExcel'><i class='fa fa-download'></i>&nbsp; Exportar a Excel</a>"+
 "</li>" : null)} nextString"
```